# Why does not AsyncTask automatically update GraphView after append new data?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-graphview

My main `Thread` extends from `Activity`, it starts two asynchronous tasks that gather data from different UDP sources. One of this tasks should append the data to [this](http://www.android-graphview.org/) graph drawing library. I am making updates on the UI from the `onPostExecute` section of `AsynTask`:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    edt2.setText(Integer.toString(result));
    // Graph Update
    if (graphActive) {
        exampleSeries1.appendData(ATList.get(ATList.size()-1), true);
    } else {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

The data is passed to the graph and if I click with my finger on the display it is displayed correctly, but I want the software to update the graph automatically. The `edt2` textfield is updated automatically.

I tried the following:

```
layout.postInvalidate(); //and invalidate
```

I have no idea how to make Android to update the GraphView.

This is the respective part of the XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/graph1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="305dp" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: the LinearLayout is where your draw the graph?

Comment: consider making it a View or  just add a dummy view to the LinearLayout to see if it works. ViewGroup with no drawable and no children tend not to invalidate. Please post your results

Comment: The Graph is added into a linearlayout, by:
layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph1);
layout.addView(graphView);

Is that what you mean?

Comment: so why you invalidate the layout and dont invalidate the graphView?

Comment: was not successful, but I got it working with a Timer that updates removes and adds the graphview, so new data is written: ll.removeAllViews();
ll.addView(graphView);

Comment: that implementation isn't good. try one last thing. set a background color at the graphview and then check again with graphview.invalidate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AsyncTask is not a Ui Thread use runOnUiThread(..) instead Asynctask.

1 rl-: parent view.
 2 myView -: Child View

//Use This Method //

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        //@Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            rl.addView(new myView(getApplicationContext()));
        }
    });
```

Comment: But it should run in Background, not in the UI Thread or didn´t i get your point?

Comment: your can only update data using AsyncTask not ui because asynctask is not a ui thread.so keep update data only in background & then pass in to ui thread using ruOnUiThread() for update your graph

Answer (score 3):

The answer by @Rishabh is not correct. Both `onPostExecture` and `onProgressUpdate` are called on the UI thread. The accepted solution is more kludgy than the original track you were on, that is to update in `onPostExecute`. Doing it there is absolutely the elegant way to do. You do NOT want to call `runOnUiThread` here.

As @weakwire said: *invalidating the graph is the right way, not invalidating the layout*. Anyways, the accepted answer is not the Android way to perform a task in the background and then update the UI with the results.

Comment: This is the solution. Although you shouldn't call the `GraphView#invalidate()` by yourself. Instead, you should call the `GraphView#onDataChanged(boolean, boolean)` and it will properly invalidate not only the `GraphView` but also the `GridLabelRenderer`. Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53237088/4071001) for details.

Answer (score 0):

For changes to take effect, you need to call:

```
graphView.onDataChanged(false, false);
```

This will invalidate the `GraphView` and the `GridLabelRenderer` as @weakwire and @vkinra suggest, but this is the recommended way to go, as you can see in `GridLabelRenderer#invalidate(boolean, boolean)`'s javadoc:

```
/**
 * Clears the internal cache and forces to redraw the grid and labels.
 *
 * Normally you should always call {@link GraphView#onDataChanged(boolean, boolean)}
 * which will call this method.
 *
 * @param keepLabelsSize true if you don't want to recalculate the size of the labels. 
 *                       It is recommended to use "true" because this will improve 
 *                       performance and prevent a flickering.
 * @param keepViewport true if you don't want that the viewport will be recalculated.
 *                     It is recommended to use "true" for performance.
 */
public void invalidate(boolean keepLabelsSize, boolean keepViewport) { /*...*/ }
```

And these are the same parameters of `GraphView#onDataChanged(boolean, boolean)`, so you should play with them to ensure the best performance. Also, you can take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53197770/4071001) to see the `GraphView#onDataChanged(boolean, boolean)`'s javadoc.