# GraphView is not updated when new data is added

Tags: java, android, graph, real-time, android-graphview

I have a `GraphView` that is not updated when new data is added, it changes the Y value to accommodate for the new data, but it doesn't draw them, here is the code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    double data = 1;
    double xgraph = 5;
    GraphViewSeries sensorSeries;
    GraphView graphView;
    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        sensorSeries = new GraphViewSeries(new GraphViewData[] {
                new GraphViewData(1, 2.0d),
                new GraphViewData(2, 1.5d),
                new GraphViewData(3, 2.5d),
                new GraphViewData(4, 1.0d)
        });
        graphView = new LineGraphView(this,"TEST");
        graphView.addSeries(sensorSeries);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph2);
        graphView.setViewPort(0, 20);
        layout.addView(graphView);

        refreshButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sensorSeries.appendData(new GraphViewData(xgraph, data), false);
                graphView.redrawAll();
                myLabel.setText(""+data+" "+xgraph);
                xgraph++;
                dataAcx++;
            }
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now its chafing values but not changing UI, because you need to do such UI update operations in separate thread. You need to place all your code which is inside `onClick` in `Thread`/`Runnable`. Create `Thread` object inside `onClick` & place that code.

Refer below link :

http://karanbalkar.com/2014/05/display-graphs-using-graphview-in-android/

Comment: No need for `Thread`/`Runnable`. The `GraphView` provides a functionality to make changes take effect, please take a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53197770/4071001) for details.

Answer (score 2):

For changes to take effect, you need to call:

```
graphView.onDataChanged(false, false);
```

instead of `graphView.redrawAll()` in the `View.OnClickListener` implementation. You must play with the parameters to ensure the best performance, take a look at the javadoc in the source code:

```
/**
 * Call this to let the graph redraw and recalculate the viewport.
 *
 * This will be called when a new series was added or removed and when data was appended 
 * via {@link com.jjoe64.graphview.series.BaseSeries#appendData(com.jjoe64.graphview.series.DataPointInterface, boolean, int)}
 * or {@link com.jjoe64.graphview.series.BaseSeries#resetData(com.jjoe64.graphview.series.DataPointInterface[])}.
 *
 * @param keepLabelsSize true if you don't want to recalculate the size of the labels. 
 *                       It is recommended to use "true" because this will improve 
 *                       performance and prevent a flickering.
 * @param keepViewport true if you don't want that the viewport will be recalculated.
 *                     It is recommended to use "true" for performance.
 */
public void onDataChanged(boolean keepLabelsSize, boolean keepViewport) { /*...*/ }
```

No need for `Thread`/`Runnable` at all.

Comment: On point, and make sure to call it right after `appendData`

Answer (score 0):

Wow actually works now, took me quite a while to notice I need a Handler... Thanks, heres my code for other noobs like me:

```
refreshButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            graphHandler.post(
            graphRunnable = new Runnable()
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    sensorSeries.appendData(new GraphViewData(xgraph, dataAcx), false, 20);
                    graphView.redrawAll();
                    myLabel.setText(""+dataAcx+" "+xgraph);
                    xgraph++;
                    dataAcx++;
                }
            }
            );
        }
    });
```