# how to bind server data (JSON) to graph in fragment android studio?

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, android-graphview

The thing is , the oncreate view in fragment  is executing before the data is received from server,so the value is null
And the app stops
How do I do so that the data is received first and on create view calls the parameter.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);



    GraphView graph = (GraphView) view.findViewById(R.id.graph);
    mSeries1 = new LineGraphSeries<>(getDataPoint());
    graph.addSeries(mSeries1);

     return view;
    }
```

This is the function called.

```
 public DataPoint[] getDataPoint(){
    DataPoint[] dp = new DataPoint[]{
            new DataPoint(temp1, 1),
            new DataPoint(2, 5),
            new DataPoint(3, 1),
            new DataPoint(5, 6),
            new DataPoint(8, 3),
    };
   // graph.addSeries(series);
    return(dp);


}
```

And I have used thread in oncreate method to get the server data.

Comment: You can call graph.addSeries(mSeries1); in your asyncTask or can refresh your Graph after data is received.
This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375139/graphview-not-refreshing

Comment: I tried that.But since it is declared in oncreate view, I am unable to use graph in other functions.It shows cannot resolve symbol graph